# How do I verify a method was called?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

I have a `ICreateService` class that has dependency on `ITicketApiAdapter`. I've tried registering a mock ITicketAdaper so that it gets injected when I create an anonymous create service.

So, in setup, I have this register for the ticket adapter:

```
Fixture.Register(() =>
    {
        var ticketApiAdapter = new Mock<ITicketApiAdapter>();
        ticketApiAdapter
            .Setup( x => x.AddTicketComment(
                It.IsAny<User>(), 
                It.IsAny<Customer>(), 
                It.IsAny<TicketComment>()))
        .Returns(new SaveResult
                        {
                            Success = true, 
                            Id = Fixture.CreateAnonymous<Guid>().ToString()
                        });

        return ticketApiAdapter;
    });

Fixture.Register(() => new CreateService(Fixture.CreateAnonymous<Mock<ITicketApiAdapter>>().Object));
```

From my understanding, that should "freeze" both the `ICreateService` and `Mock<ITicketApiAdapter>` so that when I request an anonymous instance, it's the one I registered.

I have a test that looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateServiceCallsAddTicketComment()
{
    var apiTicketAdapter = Fixture.CreateAnonymous<Mock<ITicketApiAdapter>>();
    var createTicketRequest = Fixture.CreateAnonymous<CreateTicketComment>();
    var createService = Fixture.CreateAnonymous<CreateService>();

    var results = createService.CreateTicketComment(createTicketRequest);

    apiTicketAdapter
        .Verify(x => x.AddTicketComment(
            It.IsAny<User>(), 
            It.IsAny<Customer>(), 
            It.IsAny<TicketComment>()), 
        Times.Once());

    Assert.IsTrue(results.All(x => x.Success));
    Assert.IsTrue(results.All(x => x.Errors.Count == 0));

}
```

I expect the apiTicketAdapter to be the one I registered so that I can verify the method is called. If I step through, the TicketApiAdapter is called, but Moq says it wasn't.

### Edit

This is the error I get:

> CreateServiceCallsAddTicketComment threw exception: 
>   Moq.MockException:  Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0
>   times: x => x.AddTicketComment(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(),
>   It.IsAny())
>
> Configured setups: x => x.AddTicketComment(It.IsAny(),
>   It.IsAny(), It.IsAny()), Times.Never No
>   invocations performed.

Comment: What exact message of Moq it is show?

Comment: Add code of the AddTicketComment() method, please

Comment: It's in the first block of code. It's just a mock that returns a good result.

Comment: I don't understand why you expect the method AddTicketComment() is called in the x.AddTicketComment() if you don't call it in this method at all you don't have implementation of you CreateSerice as I understood correctly. As I understood in the class CreateService you should have method x.AddTicketComment() and this method should call the  AddTicketComment() ? can you show the implementation of CreateService?

Comment: The `CreateService` calls `ITicketApiAdapter.AddTicketComment()` inside `CreateService.AddTicketComment()`. So, when I call `CreateService.AddTicketComment()` I expect it to call `ITicketApiAdapter.AddTicketComment()`

Comment: Are you sure that this Fixture.CreateAnonymous<Mock<ITicketApiAdapter>>(). return the same instance as in setup and Test Method ?

Comment: No. That's why I posted this. From my understanding of AutoFixture, when you register an instance, it get's returned every time you request and anonymous version of that type, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to AutoFixture.  Looks like a very nice tool, and for automocking is more actively maintained than the DI counterparts (I use Autofac) (that's a whole lotta auto-*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you Register a code block, that code block is going to be invoked *every time* the Fixture instance resolves the requested type. This means that it's *not* frozen. If you want to Freeze something, one of the [Freeze overloads](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/03/17/AutoFixtureFreeze.aspx) are often easier to use.

Better yet, since you seem to be using Moq, may I suggest using the [AutoMoq extension](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureAsAnAutomockingContainer.aspx)?

That would enable you to rewrite the test to something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateServiceCallsAddTicketComment(new AutoMoqCustomization());
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize()
    var apiTicketAdapter = fixture.Freeze<Mock<ITicketApiAdapter>>();
    ticketApiAdapter
        .Setup( x => x.AddTicketComment(
            It.IsAny<User>(), 
            It.IsAny<Customer>(), 
            It.IsAny<TicketComment>()))
        .Returns(new SaveResult
        {
            Success = true, 
            Id = Fixture.CreateAnonymous<Guid>().ToString()
        });

    var createTicketRequest = fixture.Freeze<CreateTicketComment>();
    var createService = fixture.CreateAnonymous<CreateService>();

    var results = createService.CreateTicketComment(createTicketRequest);

    apiTicketAdapter
        .Verify(x => x.AddTicketComment(
            It.IsAny<User>(), 
            It.IsAny<Customer>(), 
            It.IsAny<TicketComment>()), 
        Times.Once());

    Assert.IsTrue(results.All(x => x.Success));
    Assert.IsTrue(results.All(x => x.Errors.Count == 0));

}
```

That's assuming that CreateTicketRequest uses Constructor Injection or Property Injection.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've been reading your blog, but I can't seem to fully grok the AutoFixture/AutoMoq features. The simple test's seem easy enough, but full setup is what I'm lacking. I want to be able to setup `apiTicketAdapter` once and then test all methods in `CreateService` are calling the different methods on the adapter. If I free ticket adapter in `[TestSetup]`, can I use Freeze in each `[TestMehtod]` to get that same instance to verify a method has been called?

Comment: Answered my own question by just trying it out ;) it seems to do what I expected. On a side note, when I try to go to your blog from a google search result, it crashes Chrome every time.

Comment: Line 6 of your code sample, should that be `apiTicketAdaptor`, rather than `ticketApiAdaptor`?